# Get window handle from EnvDTE80.Process2 object

Tags: vb.net

I have a piece of Vb.net code that finds the **nunit.exe** process like this:

```
Dim proc2 As EnvDTE80.Process2 = dbg2.GetProcesses(trans, "myPC").Item("nunit.exe")
```

Now I'd like to press a button on the window of that process so I do this:

```
Dim ButtonHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(X, 0, "Button", "Run")

SendMessage(ButtonHandle, &HF5, 0, 0)
```

But then I need the `IntPtr` window handle for `proc2` on the spot marked "X". 
How do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(proc2.ProcessID).MainWindowHandle
```